# Alternative to map<someKey , map<anotherKey,Identifier > >

Tags: c++, dictionary, containers

I would like to assign some data for for each pair of (pointer to object, name of method in that object), to later efficiently retrieve that data knowing pointer to object and name of the method.

```
class object;
class data;
```

Which container would work better:

```
std::map<object*,std::map<std::string, data> > container;
```

or

```
std::map<std::pair<object*,std::string>,data > container;
```

or, should I use something else? Please note that most of the objects have only one method, with very few objects having more then one method.

P.S. By "work better" I mean optimizing the speed of access.

Comment: they're not equivalent options.

Comment: Make the key the pair. That way you have only one allocation per node insertion and one indirection per lookup.

Comment: @Nawaz - Why are they not equivalent? Each allows to have exactly one data per object*,std::string pair....

Comment: @IlyaKobelevskiy: because the keys are different. In the first case, exactly one object can be used as key, in the second case the same object can be used many times if the `std::string` varies.

Comment: @Nawaz Yes, but at the end it boils down to the same thing - each pair (Object,string) can be used once - in first key, there will be one key per object with multiple strings for that object, in second - multiple pairs of (object,string) - hence the question, which one is best... If you think about it, each object in first case can have many strings associated with it as well...

Comment: @Kerrek SB - thanks, that makes sense... But, won't comparisons for pairs be more expensive? Or, once objects are inserted internal hash key is used and type of eky object does not matter?

Comment: @IlyaKobelevskiy: No. Comparison is lexicographic and eager.

Answer (score 1):

You mentioned that you are using Qt and that the `object` is actually `QObject`. Qt has [dynamic properties](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/properties.html#dynamic-properties) which can be used to attach data to a specific instance of an QObject with the [setProperty](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qobject.html#setProperty) member function.

Answer (score 0):

i think better design would be to put the name->data assoziation into your object. So you directly can ask the object for its supported actions. this would be even faster, because one map search was saved.

Comment: I have no control over the object itself (actually, it is QObject from qt framework)

Comment: @IlyaKobelevskiy That is actually important. I posted an answer that is a Qt based solution.